# Not able to served website using Apache server on digital ocean of Django based project

Tags: python, django, apache, digital-ocean

I had served my website on Apache server and it is Django based project. I was able to run my website from one month. Now when i have pulled my repository from github and now it is showing 500 error. When i am activating my virtual environment and i am running `python manage.py runserver my_ip_address` then it is showing everything proper in terminal but when i am trying to excess in my web browser then it is showing nothing. Then i have tried `python manage.py runserver my_ip_address:8080` then it is working properly. When i have checked my apache server error.log|tail then it is showing some error which i am attaching error low below. I am using postgres and when i was pulling my repository for the last time then after `python manage.py makemigrations`  it asked me to give one default time for one of my field and i have provided timezone.now. In last git pull i have changed many things but if there could have error then my `python manage.py runserver my_ip_address:8080` in virtual host should not work but it is working properly. I have also restarted the apache server `service apache2 restart` and i have also used with sudo.

error.log

```
[Sun Aug 05 19:06:20.530154 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31141:tid 
140598172460800] [remote 136.232.1.166:12161]   File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, 
in get_wsgi_application
[Sun Aug 05 19:06:20.530173 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31141:tid 
140598172460800] [remote 136.232.1.166:12161]     
django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Sun Aug 05 19:06:20.530182 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31141:tid 
140598172460800] [remote 136.232.1.166:12161]   File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, 
in setup
[Sun Aug 05 19:06:20.530196 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31141:tid 
140598172460800] [remote 136.232.1.166:12161]     
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Sun Aug 05 19:06:20.530204 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31141:tid 
140598172460800] [remote 136.232.1.166:12161]   File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 
78, in populate
[Sun Aug 05 19:06:20.530218 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31141:tid 
140598172460800] [remote 136.232.1.166:12161]     raise 
RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Sun Aug 05 19:06:20.530236 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 31141:tid 
140598172460800] [remote 136.232.1.166:12161] RuntimeError: populate() 
isn't reentrant
```

Comment: Did u install all dependencies again.Some times the new update from github can contain an additional packages to be installed

Comment: Yes i have installed it again. @AyeshmanthaPerera

Comment: After activating virtual environment when i am trying to run python manage.runserver my_ip_address:8080 then it is working properly. If there could have been additional requirements then this command should have shown error. @AyeshmanthaPerera

Comment: Same problem bro...if known about solutions ple share with me...

Comment: @Ankur Ranjan if you know about solutions ple share bro..I need help